# why my session didn't get expired?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, session-state

I created an empty mvc3 project.

It has one controller ("home") and 2 actions ("index", "about")

I am using sqlserver to save my session.

here's my config file.

```
 <sessionState  mode="SQLServer" cookieless="false" timeout="1" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False">
```

time out is 1 min.

in index page. i created a session

```
Session["currentTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

in my about page, I write it out in the view.

```
@Session["currentTime"]
```

First time, I opened up the about page, current time shows up. I leave the page alone for 5 mins, then go back refresh it. the old currentTime still there. I set timeout to be 1, so it should expired now and should show nothing on the page.

maybe I totally misunderstood how session works. please tell me why session value still there after its expired.

**Edit:**

its not the cache.  I added following code to disable cache. still have problem.

```
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
 <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
 <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I think I found hte problem, not sure how to fix it.

I cleared my cache from Chrome. opened up "/home/index" page to create session, then go to "/home/about" page. check the DB. there's one session created. double checked "created" and "expires" field. confirmed that it will expired after one min.

then I walked away from my computer for 5 mins. after I come back and refresh the "/home/about" page. Session still there, not expired. query my Session table, notice that "expires" field changed to 1 min + the time I refresh the page.  why expires field changed?????????

**2nd Update:**

I believe this is what the problem is.   The SQL session provider doesn't actively monitor the Expires column in the session table. Instead, sessions aren't "officially" expired until they are removed from the table, which is done with a SQL Agent job that calls the DeleteExpiredSessions stored procedure. By default, the job is configured to run every 60 seconds.

i pretty sure my sql agent is not running. but dont know how to turn it on.  please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: See my answer to check how to turn on sql agent

Answer (score 1):

There are many things which could be possible over here. The time out as set in config is "1" min, so your session variable is bound to time out.

The situation that you are facing(and I am 90% sure), is the case of caching. Your Index page default controller action must be HTTP get. Put a button inside your page and then try to refresh your web page using button. The button will make a post to server. I am sure then the session variable would not persist.

**UPDATE 2**

Please see following the link to see [how to turn on the Sql Agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191454%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Please turn it on and let us know if it worked or not

Comment: its not the cache. I think i know what the problem is, but dont know how to fix it. I edit my post, can you please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Smells like caching issue. Which browser you are in?

The session you are using in browser is a 'guest' session which is initialized for all controllers (except sessionless, of cause). Even if it get expired, new one will be created and timespamp should be placed inside. So, each time you refresh the page, you should see current time.

**EDIT:** (after the post updated).

If think it works exactly right. According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) you need to set `regenerateExpiredSessionId` field of sessionState, to re-generate expired session id. Otherwise, the existing session object is simply re-newed and re-used.

**EDIT 2:**

The previous edit would be valid, if cookieless is true. In your code, you mentioned cookieless is false, but for some reason it still acts as cookieless = true. Are you sure you have right parameters in `sessionState`.

Comment: its not the cache. I think i know what the problem is, but dont know how to fix it. I edit my post, can you please take a look.

Comment: after few hrs google search, I believe I found why its not working. update my post again.